# EC2 need suggesstion for MVC3 support

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-ec2, cloud

I want to move my projects to EC2 and need suggestion if EC2 support my project.

Basic Requirement:

1 - MVC3

2 - EntityFramework

3 - SQLServer R2

4 - FullTrust

5 - .NET 3.5/4

and which service should I go for?

Answer (score 3):

I would use AppHarbor.com. It has all of the features you mentioned (it's also cloud based) and it's free. https://appharbor.com/ You can also integrate this with Amazon via the Amazon SDK API. (You can acquire this .dll via Nuget Package Manager) - This way you can manage all your files in S3 and deliver javascript via a Content Delivery Network if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still want to hear about EC2.

Comment: AppHarbor is hosted on AWS if you're asking for latency or other reasons.

Comment: I thought AppHarbor was hosted on Azure?